# How to say I need to smoke cigarette too much just because you have not smoked for a long time in AmE

Tags: idioms, expressions, slang, sentence-request

I was writing a short story about an American in which the guy who has quit smoking, feels a strong craving for smoking after a couple of days that he has given up smoking. I wonder what is the casual way to say you want to smoke a cigarette when you have not smoked for say a day or two days?

I came across the following terms but as you know the Urban Dictionary (their providing source) is not as reliable as an authoritative dictionary should be. Also, I need an/a expression / idiom / slang that is understood by everyone in **AmE**:

1. [I'm nicing over here, man! Give me a cigarette!](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nicing)

2. [If I don't get a cigarette soon I'm gonna start nic-fittin.](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Nic%20Fittin)

Please let me know about it.

Comment: Is this for a piece of fiction?

Comment: How come James?

Comment: I doubt you'd be in this situation in real life.  If so you don't *need* to say anything.  You certainly don't need a particularly casual way to communicate this. You can just say "I want to smoke. I've not had a cigarette for two days".  It is natural and normal.  But if you're writing a story you might want a character that speaks slang.  So the answer "I'm jonesing.." is good if you are writing a story, but not if you are talking to an American (it would sound fake, because it is)

Comment: Good point James. You said it. I was writing a short story about an American in which the guy who has quit smoking, feels a strong craving for smoking after a couple of days that he has given up smoking. I know the idiom in three other languages. For instance, Russians say: "у меня ломка потому что сильно хочу курить" or in Persian they say: "Man nasakhe sigaram" or in Turkish they say: "Gerçekten sigara içmek istiyorum...," however, I was not quite syre about Am. English!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a specific term for a cigarette, but it is AmE slang to say, "I am [jonesing](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/jonesing/) for..." anything that you have a particularly strong craving for or addiction to.  According to the link above, this slang originated among heroin addicts, but it is used for other things now, so you can say,

> "I'm really jonesing for a cigarette!  Can I [bum one off](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bum+off) you?"

Comment: Thank you very much @Canadian Yankee, but how about "I'm feening for a cig"?

Comment: @A-friend I’ve never heard “feening”; “jonesing” is what you want.

Comment: I've never heard "feening" before.